# What is `Error in array(NA, c(J, K)) : 'dims' cannot be of length 0` indicative of?

Tags: r, dimensions, lme4

I am trying to use the `mediation` package to fit a mediation model based on GLMM regressions fitted using the `lme4` package:

```
library(mediation)
library(lme4)

curvature_full_model <- lmer(scale(curvature_sqrt) ~ scale(edit_session_length) + scale(edit_session_duration_log) + scale(edit_session_number_sqrt) + scale(role_within_artifact_group_ratio) + scale(role_within_community_binary_ratio) + scale(diversity_in_contributors_prior_work_history_transformed) + (domain || article), data = data[complete.cases(data),], control = lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"), REML = TRUE)
summary(curvature_full_model)

quality_full_model <- lmer(scale(artifact_quality) ~ scale(curvature_sqrt) + scale(edit_session_length) + scale(edit_session_duration_log) + scale(edit_session_number_sqrt) + scale(role_within_artifact_group_ratio) + scale(role_within_community_binary_ratio) + scale(diversity_in_contributors_prior_work_history_transformed) + (domain || article), data = data[complete.cases(data),], control = lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"), REML = TRUE)
summary(quality_full_model)

med <- mediate(curvature_full_model, quality_full_model, treat = "scale(diversity_in_contributors_prior_work_history_transformed)", mediator = "scale(curvature_sqrt)", sims = 500, boot = FALSE)
summary(med)
```

This, however, delivers the following error message:

```
Error in array(NA, c(J, K)) : 'dims' cannot be of length 0
In addition: Warning message:
In ranef.merMod(object, condVar = TRUE) :
conditional variances not currently available via ranef when there are multiple terms per factor
```

My question is: in this case, what is `Error in array(NA, c(J, K)) : 'dims' cannot be of length 0` indicative of?

Comment: ["treat - a character string indicating the name of the treatment variable used in the models. The treatment can be either binary (integer or a two-valued factor) or continuous (numeric)."](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mediation/versions/4.4.6/topics/mediate) `"scale(diversity_in_contributors_prior_work_history_transformed)"` is not the name of a variable. I suggest you scale prior to fitting the models.

Comment: @Roland - what you are saying is wrong, if you run `scale()` within the formula, that becomes part of the variable name.

Comment: If you are sure that `mediate` can deal with that ... Have you tested my proposed fix? You don't provide a reproducible example here ...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in a multilevel mediation analysis and got the same error message "Error in array(NA, c(J, K)) : 'dims' cannot be of length 0". The error was due to the double-bar notation for the random part `(1 + treat || L2unit)` respectively the resulting exclusion of the covariance between random intercept and random slope.
The following model worked without error message:

```
summary(model.m <- lme4::lmer(mediator ~ 1 + treat + 
                             (1+treat|L2unit), data=Data)

summary(model.y <- lme4::lmer(outcome ~  1 + treat + mediator + 
                             (1+mediator|L2unit), data=Data)

medEffect <- mediation::mediate(model.m=model.m, model.y=model., 
                                treat="treat", mediator="mediator",
                                group.out="L2unit")
```